# What does the expression count?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, co.combinatorics

Let $q \geq 2$.  What does the expression $(q^n-1)(q^n-q)(q^n-q^2)(q^n-q^3)\ldots(q^n-q^{n-1})/n!$ count?  If $q$ is a prime power, then this is
the number of bases of an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field with $q$ elements.

Comment: That's something I have been wondering for a long time too. Thanks for asking!

Comment: Martin, it looks like MO witnesses the whole collection of your problems collected during the past years. This question may be an interesting one but (1) you already have an answer for some reasonable case and (2) you don't explain why it could be important to interpret the sequence as counting. A more natural Q could be why is your number integer and, if you insist, ask for a combinatorial proof of this fact.

Comment: I don't understand: what is the difference between "what does it count" and "a combinatorial proof of this fact"?

Comment: @Darji, without any motivation there is no difference. If somebody comes to ask this question for curiosity reasons, it's fine, but if this somebody asks at the same time 10 curiosity questions, this has a different flavour. Personally, I don't like to be restricted by requirement to give a combinatorial proof, or a geometric proof, etc. I like to decide myself what is the best way to show something.

Comment: @Darji, the "fact" (that the expression in question counts the number of bases of an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field with $q$ elements) only holds when $q$ is a prime power.  I believe the OP wants a more general fact that works for all integer $q \geq 2$.

Comment: @rdchat: if you follow carefully Darji's comment, you'll find that this is exactly what Darji is interested in. Yes, the intrigue is to give a counting interpretation for $q$ an arbitrary integer $>1$. A preliminary exercise: prove that the number is an integer. (Only elementary number theory is required!)

Comment: @Wadim:  I think this is a perfectly respectable question to ask, and it is likely to lead to some interesting combinatorics.  For example, the polynomial 1/n sum_{d | n} mu(d) q^{n/d} counts, when q is a prime power, the number of irreducible polynomials over F_q.  If one asks what this polynomial counts for general q, one gets several interesting answers, e.g. the number of Lyndon words of length n over an alphabet of q letters, the dimension of the nth graded part of the free Lie algebra on q generators...

Comment: @Martin: probably you already know this, but (1+q)(1+q+q^2)...(1+q+...+q^{n-1}) is the generating function for permutations with respect to inversion number.  Unfortunately I can't think of an obvious way to get a free action of S_n on any combinatorial quantity related to this.

Comment: @Qiaochu: At the end it sounds a reasonable question but in a line of strange ones. However the response below isn't related to the OP, and I really doubt that there is an answer besides the one given by Martin.

Comment: Hi, Wadim, see 
http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/474/  

Answer (score 4):

This is a partial answer...perhaps someone will improve on it!

Historically, most of the $q$-analog formulae (beginning from Euler) were derived based on the assumption that  $|q|< 1$ (to ensure series convergence) or $q=p^k$ for a prime $p$.   John Baez in one of his weekly finds ([week184](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week184.html)) discusses the geometric interpretation of $q=1$ (counting over $\mathbb CP^n$), $q=-1$ (counting over $\mathbb RP^n$) and $q=$a prime power (counting over PG($\mathbb F_q$)).  There is no discussion for other values of $q$.

However, in [Gasper and Rahman's Basic Hypergeometric Series](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521350492), there is an *inversion identity* on page 4 which can be used when $|q| > 1$:

> $(a; q)_n = (a^{-1}; p)_n (-a)^n p^{-n(n-1)/2} $ where $p=1/q$.

This returns a new expression in base $|1/q| < 1$.   You can see some examples of the identity being applied in [Gasper's Lecture Notes on q-series](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~george/preprints/ggLecNotesq-Series/index.html) (Exercise 1.1, Exercise 2.3, pg 14)

I have no idea how to interpret the result geometrically.  Could it be relevant to [Buildings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Building_%2528mathematics%2529), [Buekenhout geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buekenhout_geometry) or $p$-adic geometry?